# If input type is set to Number how to set maxlength using sapui5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I want to set validation in input field when type is set to Number and set maxlength using sapui5. But it is not working.

```
var Price = new sap.m.HBox({
    items:[new sap.m.Label({text:"Per Unit Price",required:true,design:"Bold",width:"110px"}),
    new sap.m.Input("Price",{ width:"150px",type:"Number",
          value:{
              type : 'sap.ui.model.type.Integer',
              constraints : {
                minLength: 1,
                maxLength: 15
           }
        }

    })]
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Description of method setMaxLength of sap.m.Input from [API](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Input%23methods/setMaxLength):

This parameter is not compatible with the input type sap.m.InputType.Number. If the input type is set to Number, the maxLength value is ignored.

So it means you have to find other way how to do this. For example, when you use sap.m.InputType.Tel format instead, maxLength method works:

```
var oInput = new sap.m.Input("Price",{ 
      width:"150px",
      type:"Tel",
      minLength: 1,
      maxLength: 15 
});           
oInput.placeAt('content');
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/cajukuxihu/1/edit?html,js,output) is interactive example.

EDITED 17:30 090117:

I edited previous posted code allowing to type just numbers as you wanted (Please, try [here](http://jsbin.com/tuzowidave/1/edit?html,js,output)):

```
    var sNumber = "";
    var oInput = new sap.m.Input("Price",{ 
          width:"150px",                  
          minLength: 1,
          maxLength: 15,
          liveChange : function(oEvent){                    
                          var value = oEvent.getSource().getValue();
                          var bNotnumber = isNaN(value);
                          if(bNotnumber == false)sNumber = value;   
                          else oEvent.getSource().setValue(sNumber);                    
          },
         
    });           
    oInput.placeAt('content');
```

Answer (score 2):

The [API reference of `setMaxLength`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.Input#methods/setMaxLength) says:

> This parameter is not compatible with the input type `sap.m.InputType.Number`. If the input type is set to Number, the `maxLength` value is ignored.

So, remove the type of Input field and keep it default String and set min and max length:

```js
// Input required from "sap/m/Input"
new Input({
  value: {
    path: "/value",
    type: "sap.ui.model.type.String",
    constraints: {
      maxLength: 2,
      minLength: 1
    }
  }
});
```

Above code does not allow me to enter more than 99 (2 digits).

In case Number type Input field is required.
Below code will not allow me to successfully enter value more than 100.

```js
new Input({
  type: "Number",
  value: {
    path: "/value",
    type: "sap.ui.model.type.Integer",
    constraints: {
      minimun: 0,
      maximum: 100
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Below code for sap.m.Input with input type "Number" is not working anymore. I tested it on 1.71.30 version or higher. It is possible to enter infinite amount of digits

Comment: @Denis I just tested the above code snippets and they work well. Keep in mind that the above approach doesn't limit how many digits the user can actually enter, but it does prevent storing the new value to the model if the validation fails due to the exceeded constraints. The framework will then change the value state of the Input and display a message that the entered value is incorrect, if [`handleValidation`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/a90d93df5a024e8bb18826b699c9aaa7) is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you use in the xml view the type 'Number', then it will not take in consideration the 'maxLength' property anymore.
So you have to add in the 'liveChange' event of the Input control a function that will do the validation on each change of character.

```
        onChangeCheckLength4: function (oEvent) {
        if (oEvent.getSource().getValue().length > 4) {
            oEvent.getSource().setValue(oEvent.getSource().getValue().slice(0, -1))
        }
    },

     <Input id="test"
                type="Number"
                liveChange="onChangeCheckLength4"
                value=""/>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, i have edited my answer. Can you please check?

Answer (score -1):

try this on XML in the liveChange event of a Input (liveChange="_typeNumber")

On Controller:

```
    _typeNumber: function(oEvent) {
        var value = oEvent.getSource().getValue();
        var bNotnumber = isNaN(value);
        if (bNotnumber === true) {
            oEvent.getSource().setValue(value.substring(0, value.length - 1));
        }
    }
```